# Why using 'this' keyword when accessing property?

Tags: javascript

```
let a = {
  X: 'Hello',
  Y: function(){
    console.log(this.X) // Hello
  }
}
```

why we need to use keyword 'this' to access X

why not access it directly like variable without `this.`

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Yeah it doesn't work, but why

Answer (score 2):

this = object scope and no this window scope

Try this.

```js
var X = "Out hello";
let a = {
  X: 'Hello',
  Y: function () {
  //console.log(self);    // the window object
    console.log(this);    // the {X,Y} object itself
    console.log(X);       // Out hello
    console.log(this.X);  // Hello
  }
}
a.Y();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```